# changing state derived from props before render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following React [MUI](https://material-ui.com/api/switch/) Switch component which changes its ui state on the the prop `checked = {this.state.checked}`

```js
class Switch extends Component {
    state = { 
      active : this.props.contData.statesValue.active,
      checked: false
     }
    render() { 
        const { classes, theme } = this.props; 
        return ( 
            <MuiSwitch checked={this.state.checked}/>      
        )
    }
}
```

The switch expects the checked prop to be a string , `'true'` | `'false'`.

I am trying to set the checked prop using the state active : `this.props.contData.statesValue.active`, however, this is received as bool 0 1 and when passed into Switch props as `checked={this.state.active}` results in the error

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `checked` supplied to `SwitchBase`.

So my question is this  how can I change the incoming active prop from 0 1 to a string `'true'` | `'false'` prior to the component being rendered. Previously I would have looked towards the method componentWillReceiveProps, but seeing as this is now deprecated, any pointers on how I can achieve this would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

[MUI's Switch](https://material-ui.com/api/switch/) can use either a string or a boolean for the `checked` prop, with v1.0+.

In this case we cast the prop to a boolean when initializing the state, using the tried and true `!!` double negation:

```
class Switch extends Component {
    state = { active: !!this.props.contData.statesValue.active };

    render() { 
        return <MuiSwitch checked={this.state.active}/>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the props come as integer (0 or 1), you can do this trick (hack?):

```js
render () {
  // [...]

  const checked = `${Boolean(this.props.contData.statesValue.active)`}
  // const checked = `${this.props.contData.statesValue.active}` // if it's true or false

  return ( 
    <MuiSwitch checked={checked} />      
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Switch#checked` in Material UI also accepts a boolean.

If you don't have other reasons for holding the `checked` state in the component, just pass it along from props to the `Switch` like this:

```
class Switch extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( 
            <MuiSwitch checked={this.props.contData.statesValue.active === 1}/>      
        )
    }
}
```